# Why in the definition of a straight line we ask the tangential acceleration to be $0$ and not the normal acceleration to be $0$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, intuition, geodesic

In Lee's book about Riemannian manifolds, I read

> We want to think of a geodesic as a curve in $M$ that is “as straight
> as possible.” An intuitively plausible way to measure straightness is
> to compute the Euclidean acceleration  $\ddot{γ}(t)$ as usual, and
> orthogonally project $\ddot{γ}(t)$ onto the tangent space $T_{γ(t)}M$.
> This yields a vector $\ddot{γ}(t)^{T}$ tangent to $M$, the
> tangential acceleration of $γ$. We could then define a geodesic as a
> curve in $M$ whose tangential acceleration is zero.

For me this is not so intuitive since a straight line in the Euclidean space can have tangential acceleration other than $0$. I would intuitively say that the orthogonal acceleration should be $0$. There is something I don't understand here.

Comment: Consider great circles on the $2$-sphere $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. These are geodesics, but they have nonzero nonzero acceleration normal to $S^2$.

Comment: Can you be precise about why a straight line would have non-zero tangential acceleration?

Comment: @ArcticChar, $(t^2,0,0)$ is straight in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but it has an acceleration of $(2,0,0)$ no?

Comment: Perhaps the curve is assumed to be parametrized by arc length instead of being arbitrarily parametrized?

Answer (score 0):

Because, at the end of the day, a geodesic is not really a straight line, even in Euclidean space. A geodesic is something more than that.

Take your example: the set of
$$ \{ (t^2, 0,0) : t\in [0,1]\}$$
is a portion of a straight line, but the mapping $\gamma : [0,1]\to \mathbb R^3$, $\gamma(t) = (t^2, 0,0)$ is not a geodesic.

The **definition** of geodesics in $\mathbb R^3$ is that there is no acceleration: that is, $\gamma '' =0$. The by-product is that (1) the image is a straight line, and (2) it is the shortest curve joining any two points.

In general, a curve $\gamma$ in $M$ (a submanifold in Euclidean space) is a geodesic if and only if $(\gamma'')^\top = 0$.

You might not like this definition since it does not correspond to the geometric object (straight line) but rather a mapping. But object defined in terms of mapping (instead of subsets) are much convenient to work with, since it has extra structure.

Another highly related post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665285/what-does-it-mean-being-geodesic-is-not-invariant/665391#665391)